# Need to wait for heroku-connect SFID

Tags: angularjs, node.js, postgresql, heroku, salesforce

I'm facing a challenge on using heroku-connect with Salesforce. I'm inserting a record into a parent object (order) on PG db and I get the PG id when I do the insert, then I have to insert the child (order lines) but heroku-connect hasn't done the insert into Salesforce and I don't have the SFID to be able to insert it.
What would you guys recommend I do? Do I do a requery of the field that tells me if it's synched and refresh the $digest in NG? Or do I do it on the API backend with a interval. I'm a little lost on what route to take.
I'm using streaming API but still can't get the SFID from the callback when I do the insert.

```
rows: [ { id: 85, sfid: null } ],
```

**EDIT**

Got this from Heroku support, works great.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/herokuconnect#relationships-between-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ran into this issue before, when we were evaluating Heroku Connect. We ended up with writing our own sync due several limitations of our data model.

In your case, before saving record into Postgres database, I would suggest to send API REST call to SFDC in order to get SFDC Id - only after that persist a record into Postgres. It will keep data model on SFDC/Postgres side consistent. At the same time API call limit utilization will be relatively low as you will be using API only for record creation.

As you are using Heroku Connect(not stand alone sync app) I would not recommend to put backend scheduler into your web app to control refresh of populated Ids. Logic will be highly coupled and might be painful in future to support you system

Comment: I know you are not using the product but got this from Heroku support, I changed it on all my endpoints and it works. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/herokuconnect#relationships-between-objects

Comment: that's awesome! I wish Heroku had this 2 years ago. At that point of time their tool was expensive and worked with decent number of bugs - which became deal breaker for us.